# How to make Nokogiri scrape a local server running on localhost:(port)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, localhost, nokogiri

I'm trying to test scraping of my site in development on a rails server on my local machine (locahost:3000). So far this is what I've tried:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://localhost:3000'))
```

That results in this:

```
OpenURI::HTTPError: 500 Internal Server Error
```

How do I get it to return the localhost site?

Comment: Look at your rails server, it will show you the error message.

Comment: @pguardiario yes, the error it gave is: OpenURI::HTTPError: 500. I've added it to the question

Comment: No I'm talking about the server log which will go to stdout.

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri problem because you're using `open` after using OpenURI. Nokogiri doesn't get any data until `open` succeeds.